# vim's current highlighed language

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

How to know which programming language is set for highlighting the syntax in vim.
I can set the language by "setf" command, but how to get the current language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can type `:set ft?` (Note that the question mark is part of the command)

Answer (score 10):

try `:echo &filetype`. You can also put `%{&filetype}` in the statusline setting.

Also see [this vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Showing_syntax_highlight_group_in_statusline)

Comment: :echo &fileformat doesn't return the programming language name, try ":setf cpp", then ":echo &fileformat" and you get unix again.

Comment: @MKo: yes because I have told stupidly fileformat instead of filetype.

Comment: @MKo: If you are happy you should accept Peter's answer by clicking on the checkmark below the answer score. That's how this site works.